# Need help with customalert that it would read on a normal page, but not in WordPress

Tags: functions, javascript

I made a custom alert script that works in a regular html website, but not on WordPress (WordPress is very picky on what it likes and doesn't like). This is my code:

```
    function CustomAlert(){
this.render = function(dialog){
    var winW = window.innerWidth;
    var winH = window.innerHeight;
    var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
    var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
    dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
    dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
    dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px";
    dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
    dialogbox.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = '<a>test</a>'
    document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;
    document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<div class="alertokbtn"><button onclick="Alert.ok()">OK</button></div>';
}
this.ok = function(){
    document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
    window.location.innerHTML = dialog;
}
}
var Alert = new CustomAlert();
```

And I run this script with `<button class="button" onClick="Alert.render('Alert test.');" id="btn1">Get alert</button>`. I know it is doing something, because when I press the button, it gives me errors in the debugger. These are my errors, if it helps:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
at CustomAlert.render (customalert.js:12)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):76) 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
at CustomAlert.render (customalert.js:7)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):76)
```

Thanks :)

Link add code:

```
function CustomAlert(){
this.render = function(dialog, redirect){
var winW = window.innerWidth;
var winH = window.innerHeight;
var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px";
dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
dialogbox.style.display = "block";

dialogbox.innerHTML = "<div id='dialogboxhead'><a>Test</a></div>" +
    "<div id='dialogboxbody'>" + dialog + "</div>" +
    "<div id='dialogboxfoot'><div class='alertokbtn'><button onclick='Alert.ok(" + redirect + ")'>OK</button></div></div>";

}
this.ok = function(redirect2){
document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";

window.location = redirect2;
}
}
var Alert = new CustomAlert();
```

Comment: Do you actually have those  elements present in the HTML body of the page, e.g. `dialogboxhead` is it actually present in the HTML itself?

Comment: You can try to echo the actual alert HTML markup and the JS code in the same statement just to make sure everything is actually being outputted as expected.

Comment: @kabiir I do have them present as this: `<div id="dialogoverlay"></div>
<div id="dialogbox">
  <div>
     <div id="dialogboxhead"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxbody"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxfoot"></div>
    </div>
</div>`

Comment: The error you're getting incidents otherwise. Try to start small and create just one empty `<div>` element and a button with `onclick` event which adds some `innerHTML`to it. If this works, then work your way up until you find your bug/typo. This is how I would've debugged.

Comment: Since you're not using any external JS libraries, the above method should work and help you find the root of the problem.

Comment: @kabiir Ok, I'll try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some elements that you're referencing to on your JavaScript, do not exist by the time you execute the code.

**Elements that should exist before the JavaScript:**

- dialogoverlay
- dialogbox
- dialogboxhead
- dialogboxbody
- dialogboxfoot

**Based on the error message, these elements DO exist:**

- dialogoverlay
- dialogbox

**A few questions to clarify**

- Did you check if the elements exist by the time you execute your JavaScript? (dialogboxhead, dialogboxbody, dialogboxfoot)
- Are those elements created via JavaScript or did you add them directly to your html page?

  - If you add them directly, did you add them to the php page or via WYSIWYG?

**First Test**

1. Open Google Chrome
2. Load your web page
3. Open Google DevTools (F12 -or- Ctrl+Shift+I -or- Menu icon > More Tools > Developer Tools)
4. This will take you to the Elements tab which contains the loaded HTML and in page JavaScript
5. Click on any Element and then press Ctrl+F to open the search box.
6. Type the ID with the symbol # before it. E.g. #dialogoverlay (Do this for each ID)
7. Check if the search finds anything. If it does not, that's the issue.

**Second Test**

Replace your code and see what happens (*I didn't test this code, just give it a try*)

```
function CustomAlert(){
this.render = function(dialog){
    var winW = window.innerWidth;
    var winH = window.innerHeight;
    var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
    var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
    dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
    dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
    dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px";
    dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
    dialogbox.style.display = "block";
    // ---> CODE CHANGES FROM HERE
    dialogbox.innerHTML = "<div id='dialogboxhead' style='color:red; background-color: yellow;'><a>Test 2</a></div>" +
        "<div id='dialogboxbody' style='color:red; background-color: yellow;'>" + dialog + "</div>" +
        "<div id='dialogboxfoot' style='color:red; background-color: yellow;'><div class='alertokbtn'><button onclick='Alert.ok()'>OK!!!!!!</button></div></div>";
    // <--- TO HERE
}
this.ok = function(){
    document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
    window.location.innerHTML = dialog;
}
}
var Alert = new CustomAlert();
```

Comment: Nevermind. I do have this on the HTML page before the Alert.render() : `<div id="dialogoverlay"></div>
<div id="dialogbox">
  <div>
     <div id="dialogboxhead"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxbody"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxfoot"></div>
    </div>
</div>`

Comment: Use Chrome (or Firefox). Open the Developer Tools (F12) and search for the IDs I mentioned in my answer. All of the IDs should show up under the Elements tab (Chrome Developer Tools).

When you say "I do have this on the HTML page before the Alert.render().". What do you mean by "before"? Could you post the code?

Comment: Were you able to test this? Please refer to the section "Basic Testing" on my answer (updated).

Comment: I'm about to test it :)

Comment: It found everything. What I mean by before, is that I have the divs before the calling the function. For example <div class="test"></div> and then <script>Alert.render('Hi');</script>

Comment: Since it says it cannot find 'Alert', I think it has to do something with this line: `var Alert = new CustomAlert();`

Comment: Your error message says "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' " which happens on "render" that was invoked by the event "onclick". Hold on, let me get my laptop and I'll give you a code to test.

Comment: Yes, it tells me that

Comment: Before I post the code, is your page live or can I some how see it?

Comment: No, :p the thing I'm making the site for is getting the server soon, don't know when, but I'm starting to make it

Comment: Check the **Second test** section of my answer. I didn't test the code, but it seems OK :p

Comment: Nope, I still get `Uncaught ReferenceError: Alert is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):79)`

Comment: I made a mistake with the quotes. Refresh the page.

Comment: @FranciscoF., if that worked, it means the elements that you previously created do not exist or are not being added to your HTML. Anyhow, if this works and you're happy, great!

Comment: I have another question closely related to this. I added something to when the Ok button is pressed, it will take you to a link you establish in Alert.render. For example, `Alert.render('Test message', 'https://google.com');`. For some reason it's not working. I will post the code in my question. Thanks

Comment: Hey Francisco, were you able to fix the last issue? You put the new code, but no error messages or details. Anyway, I believe the issue is that you are not passing the parameter as string. It should look like this:
`<button onclick='Alert.ok(""" + redirect + """)'>OK</button>`